# Visual Studio 2017 Automatically Link Dependencies of Dependencies

Tags: opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2017, dependencies, static-libraries

I have library A, which depends on OpenCV. I have executable B, which depends on library A.  With the following lines in my cmake, I can link A to B without needing to link OpenCV to B:

```
add_library(A STATIC ${A_src})
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(B src/driver.cpp)
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE A)
```

Great. Now, I have program C, which is premade to run in Visual Studio 2017 without cmake.  I have added the include directory, library directory, and .lib files associated with A to the properties of my solution for C.  However, C can't build because it can't find OpenCV.

While it's easy enough to link C to OpenCV, I don't see why I should have to. I know that C must be able to be linked to A without also needing to be linked to OpenCV, because I accomplished it with B.  However, I am not sure how to replicate this with Visual Studio.

If anyone could help explain to me what I am doing wrong I would be very grateful. I've learned a bunch about cmake and visual studio the past few weeks but obviously I've still got a ways to go.

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing your first `target_link_libraries` call to use [`PUBLIC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#libraries-for-a-target-and-or-its-dependents) instead. This will make sure the OpenCV libraries are added to the link interface for `A`, and access to them will be propagated to transitive dependents.

```
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. Any other suggestions?